# Как загружать с сервера разные версии javascript при различных настройках HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE?

Tags: javascript

Как например сделано по ссылке
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&client=gme-addictive&channel=geocoder-tool&libraries=places
 при различных настройках HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE на клиенте выдаётся разный текст самого javascript кода

Answer (score 0):

```
файл php:

$srcs= [
    "ru" => "https://code_one.js",
    "en" => "https://code_two.js",
    "gb" => "https://code_three.js",
];


<script src="<?=$srcs[substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2)];?>"></script>
```